# Big windows on windows forms are slow and freezes

Tags: c#, windows, forms, size

I've encountered a problem when I try to create a windows forms window in a large size (for example, 4500X4500- I use VScroll and HScroll for that purpose) filled with pictured boxes. It is taking a long time to initialize the window, and when it is finally created, It is reacting very slow, often freezes and even froze my entire computer for a while.
When I tried to initialize it for 5000X5000, it even threw an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Error creating window handle.

this is the intialization code:

```
 public Map(int width, int height, ToolBox toolbox)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        toolBox = toolbox;
        this.Width = width * 50;
        this.Height = height * 50;
        pic = new PictureBox[width, height];
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                pic[i, j] = new PictureBox();
                pic[i, j].Size = new Size(50, 50);
                pic[i, j].Left = i * 50;
                pic[i, j].Top = 24+ (j * 50);
                pic[i, j].Click += Map_Click;
                this.Controls.Add(pic[i, j]);
            }
        }
        VScrollBar vScrollBar1 = new VScrollBar();
        vScrollBar1.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
        this.AutoScroll = true;
        Controls.Add(vScrollBar1);
        HScrollBar hScrollBar1 = new HScrollBar();
        vScrollBar1.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        this.AutoScroll = true;
        Controls.Add(hScrollBar1);
    }
```

Note that it works perfectly fine when the sizes are lesser, like 2500X2500.

Edition:
Pay attention that the sizes stated are the width*50,height*50, not the width, height.

Comment: Obviously, creation time increases as width and height increase: It creates (height * width) PictureBoxes. Assuming parameters width and height are 100 for the 5000x5000 variant, it's creating 10000 of them. Perhaps you could tell us what it is you want to achieve, so we can suggest a better way?

Comment: To display fragmented map you can make a control, which only operates with images (not controls), provides scrool/zoom, but more importantly virtualization. In your case you are more likely run out of memory (stressing GC).

Comment: What do I want to achieve? A window that contains pictures all over it.

Comment: And you found out that it's not going to work this way. As Sinatr said, you need to virtualize your data, so only those images that are visible are actually loaded. There's no "The Solution" to this problem.

Comment: do you mean that only the pictures that can be seen on the normal window will actually will be loaded, and the other pictures would be dynamically loaded on the other pictures place?

Comment: Exactly. As you scroll, you load images on demand (and discard the ones you don't need anymore).